# How to change the thickness of the two rules in the titlepage created with "frontespizio" package

Tags: titles, frontespizio

I urgently need to increase the the thickness of the rules in the titlepage created with "frontespizio" package. I have no idea how to do that!

Any help will be really apreciated. Thank you!

Comment: With the amount of information given, a fast answer can only be given by the enlighted egreg.

Comment: The question title and the text don't match. Do you mean about increasing the width of the top and bottom rule, maybe for making them to reach the paper border?

Comment: I need to increase the width of the rules just a bit. Sorry, for my English.. I'm Italian..

Comment: @egreg I need to increase the width because today I went to the copy shop to print my thesis. And they told me that the rules are too thin..

Comment: @Onil90 The print shop people are wrong. So you're talking about the *thickness* of the rules?

Comment: Yes the thickness! They told me they can't print the rules on the hardcover if they are too thin

Comment: The obvious alternative is to use the `norules` option. ;-)

Comment: Printing on the hardcover? Why?

Comment: @Johannes_B It's customary here to print the “good copies” with a hard cover in fake leather. On the other hand, I have seen several of them and have never been asked about this problem.

Comment: @egreg Here as well, but usually just the degree is printed on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not supported, maybe I'll add an option also for this. In the meantime you can patch the relevant command

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}

\begin{Preambolo*}
\let\texhrule\hrule
\def\hrule{\texhrule height 1pt} % <--- the default is 0.4pt
\end{Preambolo*}

\Universita{Padova}
\Facolta{Scienze Matematiche, Fisiche e Naturali}
\Corso[Laurea]{Matematica}
\Titoletto{Tesi di laurea}
\Titolo{Equivalenze fra categorie di moduli\\
e applicazioni}
\Candidato[145822]{Enrico Gregorio}
\Relatore{Ch.mo Prof.~Adalberto Orsatti}
\Annoaccademico{19??-19??}
\end{frontespizio}

% the thesis follows

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @avati91 What English version are you talking about?